command to disconnect host after the build is completed in windriver but Currently the host is getting disconnected automatically after 5 to 10mins
the host is disconnecting automatically for every 5 to 10 minutes.The command lmutil lmdown -c License.lic but this is to shut down the license but to stop host from disconnecting automatically I searched in the net and its telling to put in the shell script post build step that is to exit network or end session using exit or logout command. Is there a command to directly disconnect only after build.
